# Add items to List of Figs

Tags: table-of-contents, lists

In my thesis, two of my chapters are published articles and I've simply included them by inserting the pdf versions. So, for those two chapters, the figures don't appear on the list of figures automatically. How can I insert extra lines in the list of figures with the figure number/caption for those? (manually I mean)
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Use `\addcontentsline{lof}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thefigure}caption text}` right before the inclusion position. But this won't work for the page numbers of course. And you have to increase the figure counter manually. Perhaps a `xr` - approach, grabing the page numbers etc. would be better

Comment: Won't you also have problems with page numbers?

Comment: I might have found a way by adding `\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {fignumberhere}{\ignorespaces figcaption}}{page}{figure}`. It does involve adding figure numbers and page numbers manually but I think it should work

Comment: @Venres_13: Actually, `\contentsline` is not meant for direct usage

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong thing. I have used `\cftaddtitleline{lof}{figure}{\numberline {number}{\ignorespaces caption}}{page}` and that works fine

Comment: @Venres_13 Feel free to write up an answer describing how you solved this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue could be settled in comments